# Make my "close" button fixed when scrolling down a div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I have this box and when you click the "folder icon" it will show some text. blah blah... And there is a close button to close the window. How do I make that button `fixed` so when I scroll down to read the texts, the close button stays at the top corner always?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/217/

Comment: your fiddle looks like its doing the right thing.

Comment: The x'd button needs to stay there when i scroll through the blah blahs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey just add this code to your css

position: fixed is the right thing for you.

```
    .button_wrap{
    position: fixed;
    top: auto !important;
    margin-left: 112px;    
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7PuN3/2/)

Comment: try dragging the boxes around and you will see the icons stay in place. They should move with the boxes

Comment: @ Jenny i edited the above code.. just look at the fiddle too(not the comment)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [sticky positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning):

```
.button_wrap {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    float: right;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3HauW/238/)

Comment: I scrolled through the blah's but the X button didnt stay in place though. I want the user to be able to X out without scrolling to the top to click the X button

Comment: @JennyC It works for me on Firefox. But note that `sticky` is an experimental and its [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility) is very limited.

Comment: I am also on firefox.. interesting